# Enviar datos por AJAX a Método de un Objeto

Tags: php, ajax

Explico mi duda, estoy realizando un inicio de sesión o mejor llamada login, estoy mandando los datos por ajax para luego enviarlos a PHP. El problema o mejor dicho la duda que tengo es: como puedo pasar el ajax a un método que tengo dentro de mi clase, el método lo que quiero es que procese el ajax y si todo esta bien redirija al panel administrador. Este es mi código:

AJAX:

```
jQuery(document).on('submit','#login_admin', function(event){
event.preventDefault();

jQuery.ajax({
  url:'AQUI QUISIERA ENVIAR ESTE AJAX A MI METODO',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  beforeSend: function(){
    $('#entrar').val('Validando...');
    $('#entrar').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
})
.done(function(respuesta){
    if(respuesta.tipo == 'administrador'){
        $('#alerta_ok').slideDown('slow');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#alerta_ok').slideUp('slow');
          location.href = 'admin/admin.php';
        },4000);
    }else{
        $('#alerta_err').slideDown('slow');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#alerta_err').slideUp('slow');
        },4000);
      $('#entrar').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#entrar').val('Entrar');
    }
 })
});
```

Método PHP de Login

```
class Main {

  public function Login($usuario,$pass){
     if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
     require('serv.php');
     include 'class/funciones.php';

     sleep(2);

     if($new_consulta = $con->prepare("SELECT tkd_admin.admin_nombre, 
     tkd_admin.admin_usuario, tkd_admin.admin_clave, 
     tkd_admin.tkd_idperfil, tkd_perfiles.perfiles FROM  tkd_perfiles INNER 
     JOIN tkd_admin 
     ON tkd_perfiles.idperfil = tkd_admin.tkd_idperfil 
     WHERE tkd_admin.admin_usuario = ? AND tkd_admin.admin_clave = ?")){
     $new_consulta->bind_param('ss',$usuario,$pass);

     $new_consulta->execute();

     if($new_consulta->num_rows>0){
       $datos = $result->fetch_assoc();
       $_SESSION['usuario'] = $datos;
       echo json_encode(array('error'=>false,'tipo'=>$datos['perfiles']));
       }else{
        echo json_encode(array('error'=>true));
        echo mysqli_error($con);
       }
       $new_consulta->close();
       }
      }
      $con->close();
      }
      }
```

Eso es lo que estoy utilizando. Lo que quiero es enviar ese ajax al método de login, y lo que no quiero es enviar mi ajax a otro archivo primero y luego enviarlo al metodo login. Quisiera poder enviarlo directo al metodo de mi clase, he investigado mucho pero sigo sin conseguir nada. Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué URL estás poniendo en la llamada AJAX? ¿Cuál es el contenido de la página/servicio al que llamas?

Comment: Para hablar del nivel de seguridad sería casi mejor una pregunta diferente (porque son dos cosas diferentes) y también harían falta más datos: ¿cuál es la URL de la llamada AJAX? ¿cómo es el código de admin/admin.php para validar que el usuario está logueado?... pero te puedo comentar algunos posibles problemas: las contraseñas deberían estar hasheadas en la base de datos, cuando hay un cambio de sesión/login sería bueno que resetearas el ID de sesión, no hay penalización por fallar...

Comment: Como dice @AlvaroMontoro, son dos preguntas distintas: lo de la petición Ajax por un lado, y lo de la seguridad por otro. En cuanto a lo primero, en el parámetro `url` de Ajax tienes que poner un archivo php, **no el de la clase**, sino otro, que evalúe si los datos se pasaron y que entonces cree una instancia de tu clase y llame al método `Login`, pasándole los datos. Puedes hacerlo directamente en el constructor de la clase, pero a mi juicio eso sería desperdiciar la clase y si quieres darle más adelante un uso más amplio a la misma ya no podrías.

Comment: Entiendo @A.Cedano, eso es lo que haré. Pasare mi ajax a un controlador que evalúe los datos, y si todo esta bien le paso los datos al método de mi clase. Gracias por la aclaratoria